# Why aren't I receiving flow error emails in my sandbox?

Tags: process-builder, exception

I have a Process Builder that is failing to complete when a record is created, when I attempt to create the record a failure message is returned "We cant save this record because PB-NAME has failed".

Typically this would fire off an exception email but I haven't received any.

I have done the following:

- Ensured Deliverability is turned on
- Added my email AND user to the Apex Exception error recipient list
- Toggled between "user running flow" and "apex exception list" in my process automation error handling options (neither option works).
- Deactivated, cloned and reactivated PB.

I need to see the emails to understand what's failing, using debug logs I can see the flow is failing because of a null pointer exception but that is not enough detail.

Comment: Unfortunately process builder failures still being sent to the last user who modified the process. You can do - deactivate the process, and activate it back . This will set your user as the last modifier

Comment: Sorry this was also something I did (updated post), and it hasn't triggered the email either.

Comment: @LironC - really? Process Automation Settings should do the trick here under `Send Process or Flow Error Email to = Apex Exception Email Recipients`

Comment: I’ve tried both of these to no avail.